# .sh script cannot send email using sendmail

Tags: linux, cron, sh

So I have a real basic SH script, just to test this, it curls google and then returns the HTTP code, its just a test, this works OK! and if I run it manually it works fine and sends me an email,

```
url="https://google.com"

http_status=`curl -s --head  --request GET $url | grep 'HTTP'`

DATE=`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

echo "[$DATE]: $http_status" >> /root/test/test.log

if echo $http_status | grep "200"; then
    echo -e "Subject:Can connect to google\nFrom:test@jameswilson.io\n\n Can connect to google status: $http_status\n" | /usr/sbin/sendmail me@jameswilson.io
fi
```

I set up a crontab on root user in linux which is like this, it runs every minute, it puts the output in the test.log but no email is sent? Any ideas why?

```
* * * * * /root/test/issiteup.sh >> /root/test/cron.log 2>&1
```

Comment: In your crontab, remove `2>&1` and add `>/tmp/output.txt 2>/tmp/outpout2.txt`.  Run it, look the logs.  This way  you will know what is going on.  You can also add debug prints (or run it -x), these logs will catch these messages.

Comment: I've done this and it doesn't write any errors or anything!

Comment: Run your script in verbose mode `set -x`.  This will print everything the script does, line per line, and show you the variable values, ...  Or add echo statements in the script to know what it is doing.  If you get nothing at all, cron is not executing the script.  So check the cron logs then.